# what is the difference between intent extra and intent data?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I see any intent has `extra` field and a `data` field.

is there any difference between them or it's just a conceptual difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Data**

The URI (a Uri object) that references the data to be acted on and/or the MIME type of that data. The type of data supplied is generally dictated by the intent's action. For example, if the action is ACTION_EDIT, the data should contain the URI of the document to edit.

Data return URI

**Extras**

Key-value pairs that carry additional information required to accomplish the requested action. Just as some actions use particular kinds of data URIs, some actions also use particular extras.

Extras contains a Bundle which is an implementation of HashMap to store key values of specific data .

Extra Return Bundle

For more information About Intent extra And Data refer [this Url](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), [`getData()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getData%28%29) returns a `Uri` whereas [`getExtras()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29) returns a `Bundle`. So yes there is a difference and the difference is not just conceptual.

Answer (score 0):

Data in an intent contains a URI to operate on, such as an URI to email client. And Extras contains the bundle regarding that URI which can carry extra info for data, such as for email client, you can put in subject body etc.

Answer (score 0):

as mentiond in the documentation of the [intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) :

the data : is not a content , its a URI , that describe what should be done regarding the specified action .

and the Extras contains a Bundle which is an implementation of HashMap to store key values of specific data .

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing that the difference is conceptual. The `getExtras()` returns a `bundle` and `getData()` returns a `Uri` [see documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getData%28%29)

Usually I approach the `Uri` from `getData()` to indicate where to operate on. And the `extra` field as an `Map/Bundle` to put parameters or arguments in for whatever I'm using the intent for.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptual or label. It's somehow strange. Here data DO NOT really means data. In fact it simply DON'T MEAN CONTENT.

You should use te extra field to pass non URI data (URI, URL, tel number and such things). You may generally use Extra fields, for *simple* data

Look at [developer.android.com description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)
**data** -- The data to operate on, such as a person record in the contacts database, expressed as a Uri (Uniform Resource Identifier).

**extras** -- This is a Bundle of any additional information. This can be used to provide extended information to the component. For example, if we have a action to send an e-mail message, we could also include extra pieces of data here to supply a subject, body, etc.